# Direct print of pdf file in angular js

Tags: angularjs, wcf

Sir,

I need your help regarding to get auto print for pdf file that is getting from Service side and displaying on client side but i don't want to display this pdf file just want to fire direct print command to printer.

Thanks & Regards
Anil Athwal

Comment: Your question looks good for leave application .but here you need to explain what you try so far...